# Keras outputs probabilities instead of classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

I am trying to implement a simple neural network for multi-class classification in Keras. The code is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_dim = 55 , kernel_regularizer=l2(0.00001), 
activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer = 'adam' , metrics = ['accuracy'] )

model.fit(X_train, dummy_y, epochs = 20, batch_size = 30, class_weight=class_weights)
```

I have 55 features and I want to predict one of 8 classes (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7). I also encode `y_train` like this:

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(y_train)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
```

However, when I use `predict()` the output is the an array for the probability of each class:

```
array([[3.3881092e-01, 2.6201099e-06, 1.9504215e-03, ..., 7.0641324e-02,
    4.4026113e-01, 1.2641836e-02],
   [2.3457911e-02, 5.5409328e-04, 2.8759112e-05, ..., 2.1585675e-03,
    5.5625242e-01, 1.0208529e-01],
   [4.6981460e-01, 2.0882198e-05, 1.4895502e-01, ..., 1.3179567e-01,
    2.2908358e-01, 1.4160757e-03],
   ...
```

How should I modify the network in order to output the class with the highest probability? Like this:

```
[[0,5,7,3,2,0,0,.....]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `predict_classes` method:

```
preds_classes = model.predict_classes(X_test)
```

Those numbers you see as the output of `predict` method are the probability or confidence score of each class. Therefore, as an alternative solution, you can take the index of the maximum score which corresponds to the predicted class:

```
import numpy as np

probs = model.predict(X_test)
classes = np.argmax(probs, axis=-1)
```